# Formatar TextArea JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Estou criando uma especie de notepad, e estou tentando encontrar alguma forma, para que o úsuario consiga formatar sua letra, tamanho, cor etc em um TextArea do JavaFX. Alguém saberia se o JavaFX tem uma biblioteca especifica para isto? para que eu possa inserir acima do TextArea uma barra para formatação de texto?

Se alguém souber, agradeço!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).
Com ele voce pode definir vários estilos pro seu `textArea`.

Uma alternativa seria utilizar o [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) acho que pode resolver seu problema.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202828/javafx-multiple-colors-in-textarea-javafx-8